# Como referenciar um objeto de uma Activity para a outra?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, lógica, drag-n-drop

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo contendo vários botões, no qual permite arrastar um botão e soltar em um determinado lugar já definido no aplicativo, e cada botão tem que abrir uma outra tela com uma imagem animada (GIF) diferente, mas que tenha haver com o botão arrastado, como setar a imagem para cada botão? E como chama-la? Segue abaixo o pedaço do código que estou com dificuldade.

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

```
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);
        return true;
    }
};
    View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            int dragEvent = event.getAction();

            switch (dragEvent){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                    if(view.getId() == R.id.btA){
                        Intent TelaBoca = new Intent(TelaAprendizagem.this, TelaFala.class);
                        startActivity(TelaBoca);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é, neste trecho de código

```
if(view.getId() == R.id.btA){
    Intent TelaBoca = new Intent(TelaAprendizagem.this, TelaFala.class);

    //Trecho incluido-------------------------------------------------
    TelaBoca.putExtra("viewId", view.getId());
    //----------------------------------------------------------------

    startActivity(TelaBoca);
}
```

mandar o id da view como um Extra na intent, através do putExtra() da intent.

Depois na outra activity, você pegaria a Intent da mesma e verificaria se tem um Id listado, e mostraria a imagem correspondente.